# Extracting normal-distributed subset from a dataset in R

Tags: r

Working with a dataset of ~200 observations and a number of variables. Unfortunately, none of the variables are distributed normally. If it possible to extract a data subset where at least one desired variable will be distributed normally? Want to do some statistics after (at least logistic regression).

Any help will be much appreciated,

Phil

Comment: can you give an example using `dput`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @neuron sure, did it.

Comment: Although it is doable, I strongly discourage you selectively remove data just to get the data as you THINK you should be. That is just bad science. If your hypothesis test require normally distributed data, find OTHER TESTS, not OTHER DATA.

Comment: @GuedesBF I see your point. However, there are 2 points, why I'm thinking of it:

Comment: @GuedesBF 1) the only non-parametric test I could use for that king of data to look for correlation – Spearman method. Did it, but want to go further – and it seems to be not possible following the rules of "true statistics"; 2) the main thing is that in environmental sciences it is almost impossible to collect data with a normal distribution. So, it that case having a subset I'm asking for could help in terms of looking for correlations with other than Spearman methods.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but I believe that it is the only way I could work with that data. Also, if it possible to create a number of sets with normally-distributed samples based on column 15, I could analyze them all and compare the results to throw away bad ones.

Comment: "compare results to throw away bad ones" seems just wrong too. If the test is good, it is good, regardles of the result. There is no such thing as a "bad result". Just "bad test". Cherry-picking either the data or the results is BAD SCIENCE

Comment: @GuedesBF Thanks for the comments. What other methods could I use to look for the correlation in this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

If there are just a few observations that skew the distribution of individual variables, and no other reasons speaking against using a particular method (such as logistic regression) on your data, you might want to study the nature of "weird" observations before deciding on which analysis method to use eventually.

I would:

- carry out the desired regression analysis (e.g. logistic regression), and as it's always required, carry out [**residual analysis**](http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Residual_Analysis) (Q-Q Normal plot, Tukey-Anscombe plot, Leverage plot, also see [here](https://rpubs.com/iabrady/residual-analysis)) to check the [model assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Assumptions). See whether the residuals are normally distributed (the **normal distribution of model residuals is the actual assumption** in linear regression, not that each variable is normally distributed, of course you might have e.g. bimodally distributed data if there are differences between groups), see if there are observations which could be regarded as outliers, study them (see e.g. [here](https://statisticsbyjim.com/basics/remove-outliers/)), and if possible remove them from the final dataset before re-fitting the linear model without outliers.

However, you always have to state which observations were removed, and on what grounds. Maybe the outliers can be explained as errors in data collection?

The issue of whether it's a good idea to remove outliers, or a better idea to use robust methods was discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175/how-should-outliers-be-dealt-with-in-linear-regression-analysis).

- as suggested by [GuedesBF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13972333/guedesbf), you may want to find a test or model method which has no assumption of normality.

Before modelling anything or removing any data, I would always plot the data by treatment / outcome groups, and inspect the presence of missing values. After quickly looking at your dataset, it seems that quite some variables have high levels of missingness, and your variable 15 has a lot of zeros. This can be quite problematic for e.g. linear regression.

Understanding and describing your data in a model-free way (with clever plots, e.g. using `ggplot2` and multiple aesthetics) is much better than fitting a model and interpreting p-values when violating model assumptions.

A good start to get an overview of all data, their distribution and pairwise correlation (and if you don't have more than around 20 variables) is to use the `psych` library and `pairs.panels`.

```
dat <- read.delim("~/Downloads/dput.txt", header = F)
library(psych)
psych::pairs.panels(dat[,1:12])
psych::pairs.panels(dat[,13:23])
```

You can then quickly see the distribution of each variable, and the presence of correlations among each pair of variables. You can tune arguments of that function to use different correlation methods, and different displays. Happy [exploratory data analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis) :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment and assistance! Don't you know, why the results of Spearman correlation are different in that ways? [1] psych::pairs.panels (ER55_numb [1:n], method = "spearman"); [2] cor (ER55_numb, method = "spearman", use = "complete.obs"). Adding "complete.obs should not be an issue..

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure which variable is ER_55_numb, so can't check. But your dataset does contain missing values, so I'd guess that use = " complete.obs" will give you a different correlation coefficient compared to use = "everything" (the default in cor). Also, after looking at the code of pairs.panels, I think that it uses the cor argument use = "pairwise.complete.obs", and this can't be changed unless you copy the function, re-write it and make it changeable.